Do these capacitors affect my options for wiring this LED strip?
I picked up a generic, single color, dimmable, 24V DC, LED strip to use in a DIY spray booth recently. Looking at the circuit I can tell that each section of the strip (between the cut lines) is a group of LEDs and one capacitor in series, and each section is connected in parallel. Makes sense to me as someone with a general understanding of electricity.
The position of the capacitor confuses me a bit. I’ve read guides about wiring up ARGB circuits and they often include a note about putting a capacitor in, but they usually say to put it before all the LEDs. In this strip the capacitor is put in after the first two LEDs of each section.


Overall the capacitor in any one section shouldn’t be affecting the lights in any other section. If I were to cut out strips of any number of sections and wire them all in parallel from the first strip it would be the same as the one full length strip, right?
For my setup I’m hoping to have multiple shorter strips all powered from the same side rather than having to zig zag the strips so they’re still in a chain.

If I were to cut out strips of any number of sections and wire them all in parallel ... they are already wired in parallel ... cutting them and reconnecting them does not result in a change to the circuit

That's not a capacitor.  Wired in series like that, it would prevent current from flowing through the LEDs.
The part you see is a resistor.  It limits the current through the LEDs.
You don't need to "zig-zag" the strips or do anything else odd.  Apply power to the + and - rails and it will work.  Just don't exceed the voltage rating.

That doesn't look like a capacitor; it's probably a 47 ohm resistor. With 6 3.7V LEDs in series, it would limit current to ~40mA which seems reasonable. Looks like there are bus traces on the edges of the strip. Cut where indicated and arrange the pieces in any configuration you like.
